# Java find and replace path

Tags: java

Is it possible to `find` and `replace` in a `Path` object without converting it to a String?

For example here is a simple code snippet,

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {

    final Path wholePath = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/donkey/folder1/folder2/data.txt");
    final Path find = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/donkey");
    final Path replace = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/sym4");

    Path expected = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/sym4/folder1/folder2/data.txt"); // how to get this?

    Path path = Paths.get(wholePath.toString().replace(find.toString(), replace.toString()));

    System.out.println(expected.equals(path));
  }
}
```

Using a `.toString()` method seems to be a non-portable way and instead it's better to use the `.resolve()` or similar method?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Strings are actually pretty portable, however to avoid them you can use `.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().resolve(newDirName).resolve(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you are not actually *finding* and replacing, you are re-basing the path, i.e. you are changing the prefix of the path.

To do that, you first convert the input, i.e. `wholePath`, which is an absolute path, to a *relative* path, relative to the old root path, i.e. `find`, so you get `folder1/folder2/data.txt`, then you resolve that against the new root path, i.e. `replace`.

You do that by calling [`relativize(Path other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-) and [`resolve(Path other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-), like this:

```java
Path input = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/donkey/folder1/folder2/data.txt");
Path oldRoot = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/donkey");
Path newRoot = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/sym4");

Path relativePath = oldRoot.relativize(input);
Path result = newRoot.resolve(relativePath); // /usr/animals/data/sym4/folder1/folder2/data.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it using `Files` API, but it will just not be in single step.

```
    final Path wholePath = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/donkey/folder1/folder2/data.txt");
    final Path find = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/donkey");
    final Path replace = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/sym4");

    //here comes 2 lines of magic
    Path relativized = find.relativize(wholePath);
    Path path = replace.resolve(relativized);
    

    Path expected = Paths.get("/usr/animals/data/sym4/folder1/folder2/data.txt");

    System.out.println(expected.equals(path));
```

This basicly splits `wholePath` to "what will be replaced" and "what is left" as `relativized`. Then it resolves `relativized` path using new `root`